# Get live AAC stream in flash is delayed/pending for 5 minutes before playing on Chrome and IE but not FF

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, streaming, flv, aac

I'm not sure if my problem is from Flash or from the API I am using, but here goes:

I am creating a live stream player using a client's API all in Flex 4 (AS3).
Basically, I load the url of a "stream" (it's a AAC stream put in a FLV actually)
In Firefox, everything works fine.
But in IE and Chrome, the GET of the AAC has the status "pending" for 5.5 minutes, then it finally plays. And it does that everytime I reload the stream.

Logically, it means the load() really is just loading a FLV file, which shouldn't be any different than loading any kind of files... 
I load many files (JSON, XML, ...) in that application, but none other do that, and I get that problem only in IE and Chrome...

-- EDITED --

I did some more research and found that the culprit is probably the Flash Player.
Nonetheless, I have these versions installed:

> **Firefox** 14.0.1 --> 11.4.402.265 (works)
>   **Chrome** 21.0.1180.89 m --> 11.3.31.232 (doesn't work)
>   **IE** 9.0.8112.16421 --> 11.4.402.287 (doesn't work)

Meaning I have a more recent version of Flash on IE than on Firefox, but it doesn't work on IE and works on FF...

As far as I have read, it seemed there were streaming problems in the Flash Player version 11.2 ans 11.3, but I didn't see anything about version 11.4. (And even then, IE and FF have 11.4...)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ether.. I can't help you because I'm having almost the same problem.. I have 4 channels.. 1 is MP3 and others AAC+ and Chrome just plays MP3 stream .. I thought that it was Flash Problems or I did something wrong..

Comment: Somehow, we pinned down the problem to be because of our proxy / anti-virus ( we are using Sophos). If we get more, I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can explain this right, since I'm not a server/network person, but here goes:
It seems the problems comes from our provider AAC and Sophos/Firewall.

The requests to get the AAC stream gets analysed by our anti-virus and by our firewall. The way our flash player works is that it "asks" for a AAC server, which the API will return.
The API will try to return a server nearest to the asking location, but our connection seem to sometimes respond with a wrong location. Therefore, instead of getting a server from the same city, we get a server from across the country. And the firewall and Sophos do not like that, so they block the request and timeout (for 5 minutes), then, the API returns another server, which is valid this time.

Therefore, we had to allow the servers from across the country to go through the firewall and we are still struggling with Sophos. Hope this can help anyone...